# Inverse of an objects distance

Tags: javascript

If I have the object's `var distance;`  set at 100. As it moves towards a distance of 0, I want the opacity to increase. How would I use that 100 incrementing down to be the reverse for the opacity? Is there math I could use to do this?

Would I just use a `var count` to count up from 0 to 1?

Comment: `opacity = 100 - distance`

Comment: @Bergi (...) `/ 100`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `opacity = (100 - distance) / 100`.

This way when distance is 100 opacity will be 0 and when distance is 0 opacity will be 1.

In general if you want a transition so that as `x` moves from `xa` to `xb` `y` correspondingly moves from `ya` to `yb` you can use

```
y = ya + (x - xa) * (yb - ya) / (xb - xa)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been coding for a long time and I just can't get past the hump of asking such simple questions like this... ugh.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, your are looking for something like this :

> opacity + distance = 100

So your opacity var would follow the rule :

```
opacity = 100 - distance
```

Is that the answer you are looking for ?